# How do you keep logged in with selenium driver?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying some things with selenium. However, I was annoyed that I could keep logged in google so, after some research, I found this script (from 2017) that is supposed to keep you logged in. I've tried it, and it works partially. It opens a new driver with my account logged in but then gives me this error:
`selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: user data directory is already in use, please specify a unique value for --user-data-dir argument, or don't use --user-data-dir`

I-ve tried to remove the path, to change it to `C:\\Users\\pablo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data` but nothing seems to work. It eithers opens a driver **without** my data or one **with** my data but then gives me an error.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


options = Options()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\pablo\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path="C:/Users/pablo/OneDrive/Bureau/Projets Python/Infos Insta/chromedriver")

driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
driver.quit()
```